# JavaScript reports not getting the image from the database

Tags: javascript, database, report

I can't get an image from the database into my jsreport while running the report.

How I get an image from the database by fixing the following code?

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{:Sno}}</td>
        <td>{{:ReceiptDateTime}}</td>
        <td>{{:ReceiptNo}}</td>
        <td>{{:vClassificationID}}</td>
        <td>
          <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{:ClassImg}}" style="width:50px;height:50px" />
        </td>
        <td>{{:VClassName}}</td>
        <td>{{:VClassRate}}</td>
        <td>{{:FareCollected}}</td>
        <td>{{:CollectionMode}}</td>
        <td>{{:Username}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in https://playground.jsreport.net ? What is inside ClassImg, can you print it somewhere to see the value? Is it valid base image? Did you try to remove data-ng- and keep just src?

Comment: s nw iam getting the image i removed the data-ng .Thank you

Comment: You should probably post this as answer and accept it.